# Can't install an app downloaded from the internet

Tags: android, installation, android-sdcard

I am having problems publishing my application through the internet.

I have an application built to 1.6 or latter android system, I have published a link accessible by the mobile browser to let users download the application and install it on their phone.

The download goes with no problems in all of the devices I have tested but in 2.1 devices or lower I can t install the app and a warning message is given to me: "Application is not installed".

I google for a while at in the end I have found the problem: You can t install an application from the sdcard until version 2.2

I don t know how to get over this problem, I would really want to give users the opportunity to download the app from my web to all devices. Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an app that you can install and then install an apk from sdcard. The app is called apkInstaller. Another way to install an apk is using adb command for those ones that have installed.

Comment: Thanks dude! it helps and very easy solution

Answer (score 0):

Did you check in the manifest file the minVersion, minSdk, api-version fields ?

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/compatibility.html

Answer (score 0):

Include the android:installLocation attribute with a value of "auto" or "preferExternal" in the  element.

Refer this:http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/install-location.html

Cheers!!!

Comment: I knew about this attribute but doesn't resolve the problem because this attribute is only accepted for 2.2 or greater versions. The point is not choose where to install the application: sdcard or internal memory,  is giving the option to 2.1 or lower devices to install app downloaded from a web link.